# Recursively search parent directories when including/inputting file

Tags: input, external-files, include, paths, filesystem-access

I'm wondering if it's possible to modify the function of the \input command so that e.g.

```
\input{macros}
```

would work recursively.

**Variant 1**

1. Check if `macros.tex` exists in the current directory. If yes, include it and exit the algorithm. Otherwise go to step 2.
2. Go up to the parent directory and go back to step 1.

This will have the effect of using the macros.tex file in the current directory when it exists, and otherwise falling back to the next parent one that exists. This would already be great but even better for my purpose would be a slightly more complicated version:

**Variant 2**

1. Check if `macros.tex` exists in the current directory. If yes, include it.  In any case, go to step 2.
2. Check whether we've already reached some pre-specified "root" directory (past which we don't want to search further). If not, go up to the parent directory and go back to step 1.

This is similar but keeps including *all* the macros files that exist until we get to some specified root directory.

Comment: why up not (as all file searching is set up to do), down? You can do this by setting TEXINPUTS to a suitable value.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You're right, I did mean to go down instead of up (so that the current folder overrides the 'global' macros).

Comment: but normally you have a local area say $HOME/tex  where all your local files are so you just need `$HOME/tex//:` so anything under there is found before the standard search path, no need to go up the tree from the working directory

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Not sure I understand. Say I have $HOME/tex/project1/subproject7/notes1.tex, and a macros.tex in that directory and in all of the parent directories as well (tex/macros.tex, tex/project1/macros.tex, etc.). Then I want to import all of those macros.tex files automatically. Adding just $HOME/tex to the path won't do that as far as I understand.

Comment: `$HOME/tex//:` will do that,   `//` means recursive subdirectories and teh trailing `:` means add the standard path at the end(in fact `~/texmf` is in the default search path, so if you use that naming you don't need to set anything at all) oh no. not with the same name in the same search path you only get one

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thanks; this gives a working solution for Variant 1 which I've just tested. I'm afraid there's no way using TEXINPUTS is going to let me do Variant 2 though, since there will be multiple files with the same name, and it will just chose the one from the last search directory.

Answer (score 3):

If the current directory is

```
/users/SollteSoSein/something/latex/document
```

then

```
TEXINPUTS=.:/users/SollteSoSein/something/latex:/users/SollteSoSein/something:/users/SollteSoSein:  pdflatex myfile.tex
```

would do what you ask, not going higher than users/SollteSoSein

That is bash syntax, using `:` as the path separator, you could do the equivalent in windows setting the TEXINPUTS environment variable and using an appropriate syntax for the windows command shell (still using / but with ;)

Comment: I have hundreds of these subfolders so it's not practical to do it manually as you suggest. It does answer the question though so +1 (not actually though, since I don't have enough reputation yet).

Comment: I guess I can write a simple script to automate typing this, that should work for me. A purely LaTeX solution would still be interesting though. Thanks!

Comment: you could so something with `\input@path` but it is such a weird thing I don't see why you do not simply use `TEXINPUTS=/users/SollteSoSein/something/latex//:`  and find all files below there.

Comment: It would be _much_ faster if you just pre-indexed /users/SollteSoSein/something/latex// with mktexlsr and then kpathse would find files there without searching the disk at all, just as it does for the standard directories constructing alist of hundreds of directories to search by hand is going to make things terribly slow. @SollteSoSein

Answer (score 0):

I use the following piece of code.

The command `\loadPreambule{myFile.tex}` looks for the file `myFile.tex` in the directory `_aux_files` (in the directory where the `.tex` file is compiled); if it does not exist, it will look for it in the parent folder, etc.

It is quite ugly to my taste: so if anybody can come with a better solution, I would appreciate.

```
\RequirePackage{import}

\newcommand{\loadPreambule}[1]
{
\def\namePreambule{_aux_files/}
\IfFileExists{../_aux_files/#1.tex}
    {\def\namePreambule{../_aux_files/}}
    {\IfFileExists{../../_aux_files/#1.tex}
            {\def\namePreambule{../../_aux_files/}}
            {\IfFileExists{../../../_aux_files/#1.tex}
                    {\def\namePreambule{../../../_aux_files/}}
                    {\IfFileExists{../../../../_aux_files/#1.tex}
                        {\def\namePreambule{../../../../_aux_files/}}
                        {}}}}
%
\subimport{\namePreambule}{#1.tex}
}
```